# Add sub-folder to vinagre 3.18.2 bookmarks

Tags: gnome, gnome3

I want to organize my VNC connections using the bookmark feature integrated in vinagre 3.18.2.
Since the GUI obviously does not support the adding of sub-folders I had a look at the bookmarks file in `~/.local/share/vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks.xml`.
However due to a lack of documentation I could not figure out, what the correct syntax for adding sub-folders to the XML structure is. Hence I had a look at vinagre's source code and found the use of the variable `VINAGRE_BOOKMARKS_ENTRY_NODE_FOLDER` in several bookmarks-related C and C-header files.
But unfortunately I could not find out the correct syntax for editing the bookmarks XML file from the parser's code either.

Here's the files I searched:

`./vinagre/vinagre-window.c
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks.c
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks-entry.h
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks-migration.c
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks-tree.c
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks-entry.c
./vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks-ui.c`

How can I add sub-folders to the bookmarks anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at [vinagre-bookmarks-migration](https://github.com/simos/vinagre/blob/master/src/vinagre-bookmarks-migration.c)

To introduce a sub-folder do

`<folder name="folder name">[..]</folder>`

Where `[..]` may be items or further sub-folders.

**Update:**

I created a simple XSD file to parse the bookmarks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
Vinagre bookmarks XML Schema Description

Maintainer: Richard Neumann <r dot neumann at homeinfo fullstop de>

XXX: Use Venetian Blind Design
-->

<!--<xs:schema
    xmlns="https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0"
    targetNamespace="https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Vinagre/vinagre-bookmarks.xsd">-->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

    <xs:element name="vinagre-bookmarks" type="VinagreBookmarksRoot">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Root element for vinagre bookmarks
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>


    <xs:complexType name="VinagreBookmarksRoot">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Vinagre bookmarks root folder type
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="folder" type="Folder" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Sub-folders
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="item" type="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                        Connection items
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="Folder">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                Folder type
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="VinagreBookmarksRoot">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="Item">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                A connection item
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="protocol" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="host" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="port" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
            <xs:element name="fullscreen" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="width" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="height" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="view_only" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="scaling" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="keep_ratio" type="xs:boolean"/>
            <xs:element name="depth_profile" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
            <xs:element name="lossy_encoding" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```